# Number of straight lines can be drawn

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

> How many different straight lines can be drawn using $9$ points on the triangle of the figure below?[image]

**My try:** Considering points other than $A$, $B$ and $C$ we got $2\times3 + 2\times1 + 3\times1 = 11$. For those three points,  number of lines are $1 \times1 + 2 \times 1 + 3\times1 = 6$. So the total number is $6 + 11 + 3 = 20$ counting sides as possible lines but the solution gives $24$. What are the other lines which I'm not considering here? Also I think there is a combinatorial solution but I didn't find that.

Comment: I don't see how there are 24 lines. Brute force isn't ever the best option, but in this case, it's not so bad. Going clockwise around the triangle and starting at A, the 20 lines are: AB, AI, AC, DF, DG, DH, DC, DI, EF, EG, EH, EC, EI, BF, BG, BH, BC, IF, IG, IH.

Comment: For your intuition that there is a combinatorial solution, I can imagine there is. Certainly, this has a flavor similar to handshaking.

Comment: $N=3+a+b+c+ab+ac+bc$ where $a, b$ and $c$ are the number of points on the sides of the triangle, excluding the vertices.

Comment: @Orchid_2.718281828 Thank you for mentioning that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $9$ points and a straight line is determined by two distinct points.
We can use the binomial coefficients.

> In how many ways can we choose pairs of points?
>   $$\binom{9}{2}=\frac{9\cdot 8}{2}=36$$

But, $A,D,E, B$ are collinear as well as $A,F,G,H,C$ and $B,I,C$.
So, we have $\binom{4}{2}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{3}{2}$ *non-distinct lines*.
$$\binom{4}{2}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{3}{2}=\frac{4\cdot 3}{2}+\frac{5\cdot 4}{2}+\frac{3\cdot 2}{2}=19$$
Now, we have to take $AB, BC$ and $AC$ into account, so the final result is:
$$36-19+3=20$$

Answer (score 1):

**Note: we have the same count, but here is my solution, anyway.**

Considering that the set of points $S$ consists of the set $V$ of points that are vertices and the set $E$ of non-vertex points that lie on an edge, we can count the lines $V \to V,$ $V \to E,$ and $E \to E.$ We note that we need not find the lines $E \to V$ because these are precisely the lines $V \to E.$

Given a line $V \to V,$ our only choices are the three sides of the triangle, hence there are 3 such lines.

Given a line $V \to E,$ we can reconstruct it by first choosing a vertex point in one of three ways. Based on this choice, we obtain a different number of choices for the remaining edge point. Observe that if we choose $A,$ the only edge point that will give a new line is $I.$ Indeed, choosing any of the other edge points would give us a line $V \to V.$ Further, if we choose $B,$ the other edge points could be $F,$ $G,$ or $H.$ Last, if we choose $C,$ the other edge points could be $D$ or $E.$ Ultimately, there are $1 + 3 + 2 = 6$ such lines.

Given a line $E \to E,$ we can reconstruct it by first choosing an edge point in one of six ways. Based on this choice, we obtain a different number of choices for the remaining edge point. Explicitly, if we choose $D$ or $E,$ then we must choose $I,$ $F,$ $G,$ or $H,$ and if we subsequently choose $I,$ then we can choose $F,$ $G,$ or $H.$ Order does not matter here, so these are all the lines $E \to E;$ there are a total of $2 \cdot 4 + 1 \cdot 3 = 11$ such lines.

Overall, there are $3 + 6 + 11 = 20$ distinct straight lines we can obtain from these points.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.